# Linear operator between normed spaces finite-dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, linear-transformations

Let $X$ and $Y$ vectorial spaces finite dimensional and $u\in X$ satisfies the condition $Tu=0$ for all linear operator $T:X\rightarrow Y$, can conclude that $u=0$? It is obvious that $T$ are continuous linear operators, I cant take of this information. I need suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true if $Y$ is $0$-dimensional, but if $dimY>0$, consider a non zero vector $v\in Y$, you can find a basis $(e_1=u,...,e_n)$ of $X$ and define $f:X\rightarrow Y$ by $f(e_i)=v$, and this shows that if $dim»V>1$ and $u\neq 0$ there exists $f$ linear such that $f(u)\neq 0$ and this proves  your claim if $dimV>0$.